# Angular: Data from API returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to build chart using highchart module on Angular. The Object is provided from an API. This is the object I should have obtained.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "activity": [
        {
            "username": "aja_ditag_yo",
            "activity": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

So I build my service.ts to get those object and call it on my component.ts. This is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { AdminService } from 'src/app/services/admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-linebarchart',
  templateUrl: './linebarchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./linebarchart.component.scss']
})
export class LinebarchartComponent implements OnInit{

  chartOptions:{} = {};
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  dataRegister:any = {}

  constructor(
      public adminService: AdminService
  ) {
    }
    
    
    ngOnInit (): void {
        this.adminService.getActivity().subscribe(data => {
            this.dataRegister = data
            this.chartOptions = {
                 // some highcarts config, and dataRegister is called
                 ....
                 series: this.dataRegister.activity
            }
        })
    }
    
    
}
```

Since the `chartOptions` is inside `subscribe`. `chartOptions` returns undefined. So I moved the `chartOptions` outside `subscribe` and the highcharts appear on the page. But, the dataRegister.activity returns undefined. What should i do?

Comment: @Eyeslandic Yes, but I need the value outside ```subscribe```

Comment: @Eyeslandic  I want to build chart using highcharts module on angular. The data is provided from an API. I've edited the post, hope that can explain my problem

Comment: I'm not very familiar with highcharts, but https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-and-angular-7/ describes how to use an api to load the data.

Comment: @Yuriy Well, the example works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The function in `subscribe` is called asynchronously after the data comes back. Which means your `console.log` is called first. Use

```
this.adminService.getActivity().subscribe(data => {
    this.dataRegister = data;
    console.log(this.dataRegister.activity);
});
```

Comment: Yes, it returns value when console.log ```this.dataRegister.activity``` inside. But I need to get value from outside.

Comment: @Kaneki that's not a thing. ngOnInit will probably finish executing before the function inside `subscribe` is called. Everything you need to do with the data needs to be in the `subscribe` method. Can you explain why you need the value from outside?

Comment: I want to build chart using highcharts module on angular. The data is provided from an API. I've edited the post, hope that can explain my problem